# Extract data from txt file and create new file based on specific text dynamically

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

My file is like below 
cat `Data.txt`

```
****************** abc.txt - Starting point  ********************
abc
asd
asad
asfkn
sadjn
****************** abc.txt - End point  ********************
****************** def.txt - Starting point  ********************
fjhdsf
sdjnbs
askd
akdsn
dhskn
****************** def.txt - End point  ********************
****************** xyz.txt - Starting point  ********************
akdsnaskd
sakdnbasd
akjsndb
askjdb
akdsnb
****************** xyz.txt - End point  ********************
```

I would like to get multiple files created dynamically based on Start point and End point.

The Output I need is in above case 3 files : `abc.txt ,def.txt ,xyz.txt`

```
>> cat abc.txt 
abc
asd
asad
asfkn
sadjn

>> cat def.txt 
fjhdsf
sdjnbs
askd
akdsn
dhskn
```

Could you please help me a unix command to do this .

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What did you try so far? Can you please show us your work? Also, you might want to take a tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour - it will give you some clue on what this site is about. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy-to-read solution with `Bash` and `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line ; do
if FILE=$(grep -P -o '[a-z]*\.txt(?= - Starting)' <<< "$line"); then
F="$FILE"
fi
if ! grep '\*\*\*\*' <<< "$line" ; then
echo "$line" >> "$F"
fi
done
```

It gives the following result

```
$ cat file.txt
****************** abc.txt - Starting point  ********************
abc
asd
asad
asfkn
sadjn
****************** abc.txt - End point  ********************
****************** def.txt - Starting point  ********************
fjhdsf
sdjnbs
askd
akdsn
dhskn
****************** def.txt - End point  ********************
****************** xyz.txt - Starting point  ********************
akdsnaskd
sakdnbasd
akjsndb
askjdb
akdsnb
****************** xyz.txt - End point  ********************
$ cat file.txt | ./go.sh
****************** abc.txt - Starting point  ********************
****************** abc.txt - End point  ********************
****************** def.txt - Starting point  ********************
****************** def.txt - End point  ********************
****************** xyz.txt - Starting point  ********************
****************** xyz.txt - End point  ********************
$ cat abc.txt
abc
asd
asad
asfkn
sadjn
$ cat def.txt
fjhdsf
sdjnbs
askd
akdsn
dhskn
$ cat xyz.txt
akdsnaskd
sakdnbasd
akjsndb
askjdb
akdsnb
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWK solution:

```
awk '/^(\*[ ]*)+/ {
    gsub(/(\*[ ]*)+/,"")
    match($0,/[ ]*-[ ]*Starting point/)
    if(RLENGTH>0) fn=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    next
}
fn { print $0 > fn }' Data.txt
```

It assumes that there are no lines between "End point" and "Starting point".

Result:

```
$ cat abc.txt
abc
asd
asad
asfkn
sadjn
```